# solve_ivp from scipy does not integrate the whole range of tspan

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use `solve_ivp` from `scipy` in Python to solve an IVP. I specified the `tspan` argument of `solve_ivp` to be `(0,10)`, as shown below. However, for some reason, the solutions I get always stop around t=2.5.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optim

def dudt(t, u):
    return u*(1-u/12)-4*np.heaviside(-(t-5), 1)

ic = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

sol = solve_ivp(dudt, (0, 10), ic, t_eval=np.linspace(0, 10, 10000))

for solution in sol.y:
    y = [y for y in solution if y >= 0]
    t = sol.t[:len(y)]
    plt.plot(t, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### What is going wrong

You should always look at what the solver returns. In this case it gives

> message: 'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.'

Think of the process of solving your initial value problem with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` as repeatedly estimating a direction and then going a small step in that direction. The above error means that the solutions to your equation change so fast that taking the minimal step size possible is too far. But your equation is simple enough that at least for `t =< 5` where `4*np.heaviside(-(t-5), 1)` always gives 4 it can be solved exactly/symbolically. I will explain more for `t > 5` later.

#### Symbolic Solution

Sympy can solve your differential equation. While you can provide it an initial value it would have taken much longer to solve it once for each of your initial values. So instead I told it to give me all solutions and then I calculated the parameters `C1` for your initial value separately.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

ics = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

f = symbols("f", cls=Function)
t = symbols("t")
eq = Eq(f(t).diff(t),f(t)*(1-f(t)/12)-4)
base_sol = dsolve(eq)
c1s = [solve(base_sol.args[1].subs({t:0})-ic) for ic in ics]
# Apparently sympy is unhappy that numpy does not supply a cotangent. 
# So I do that manually.
sols = [lambdify(t, base_sol.args[1].subs({symbols('C1'):C1[0]}), 
modules=['numpy', {'cot':lambda x:1/np.tan(x)}]) for C1 in c1s]
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 10000)

for sol in sols:
    y = sol(t)
    mask = (y > -5) & (y < 20)
    plt.plot(t[mask], y[mask])
```

[image: ode solutions]

At first glance the picture looks odd. Especially the blue and orange straight line part. This is just due to the values lying outside the masked range so `matplotlib` connects them directly. What is actually happening is a sudden jump. That jumped tipped off the numeric ode solver earlier. You can see it even more clearly when you make sympy print the first solution.
[image: first solution]

The tangent is known to have a jump at pi/4 and if you solve the argument of the tangent above you get `2.47241377386575`. Which is probably where your plotting stopped.

#### Now what about `t>5`?

Unfortunately your equation is not continuous in `t=5`. One approach would be to solve the equation for `t>5` separately for the initial values given by following the solutions of the first equation. But that is an other  question for an other day.

Comment: hmmm when I use `odeint` instead of `solve_ivp` I'm able to get the curve after t=5 if for example I use `N0=10`

Comment: Also how can I prevent the "jumping solution" and just get the curves until they hit y=0?

Comment: PS: See here for what I mean more precisely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354888/how-to-prevent-odeint-from-giving-me-solutions-that-blow-up

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer Am I guessing correctly that you don't mind that Lutz Lehmann's solution in the other thread misses out on the continuation of the curve after the jump and now adding the part for t>5 would be not useful to you anyways?

Comment: Yes that's right