# How to prevent odeint from giving me solutions that blow up

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve and plot ODE using Scipy's `odeint` using different initial conditions. This is done in the code below. Note that for three of the initial conditions (2, 4, and 6), the solutions die out, then the graphs start looking weird for these 3 solutions (in the plot, it's most notable for `ic/N0 = 6`, which corresponds to the green curve, but you can also see some blue and orange on the fringes at the bottom). How do I fix this so that for those solutions that do die out eventually, I just get these curves, without the weird behavior afterwards? Obviously, one way to do this would be to just stop plotting the curves based on when the solution goes from positive to negative, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
ic = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
def de(t, u):
    return u*(1-u/12)-4*np.heaviside(-(t-5), 1)

plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 20])
for N0 in ic:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 10, 10000), tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10000), N1)
```

[image]

EDIT:
Here's a not very elegant way of solving this problem:

```
ic = [8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
ic_to_zero = [2,4,6]

plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 20])
for N0 in ic:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 10, 10000), tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10000), N1)
for N0 in ic_to_zero[0:1]:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 2, 10000), tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,2,10000), N1)
for N0 in ic_to_zero[1:2]:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 2, 10000), tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,2,10000), N1)
for N0 in ic_to_zero[2:3]:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 4, 10000), tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,4,10000), N1)
```

[image]

EDIT: I first tried and [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352999/solve-ivp-from-scipy-does-not-integrate-the-whole-range-of-tspan/69354177#69354177) about how to solve this using `solve_ivp` but things got more complicated

Comment: Just guessing: the use of heavyside function causes the function to not be smooth and consequently the solver misbehave at t=5

Comment: @Tarik right but this does not prevent it from properly plotting the other solutions with different initial conditions

Comment: Maybe you could try the different scipy ode solvers.

Comment: @Tarik I actually first tried using `solve_ivp` but it made things more complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352999/solve-ivp-from-scipy-does-not-integrate-the-whole-range-of-tspan/69354177#69354177

Comment: Wait, it seems that the solutions going below zero are all blowing up. Why not solving from 0 to 5 then from 5 to 10 independently?

Comment: @Tarik right that's a possibility, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of going about it, e.g some argument that I can pass to `odeint`

Comment: I think the question you referred me to was answered in detail in a very competent manner. You would be better off pursuing that thread. As far as complexity goes, well, c'est la vie, you have to bite the bullet and learn.

Comment: Please add links to [previous cross-posts](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/solve-ivp-from-scipy-does-not-integrate-the-whole-range-of-tspan), especially when they have answers that give the source of the observed problem in some detail.

Comment: The exact solution ceases to exist inside the integration interval, thus the numerical solution does nor fare better. Use events to stop the iteration when leaving the domain-or-interest, or replace the ODE with something bounded or linear outside this region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not interested in the negative range, let's cut off the ODE function at some negative value for `u`. In general ODE with a bounded or linearly growing right side exist for all times and are also numerically benign.

```python
ic = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
def de(t, u):
    u = max(-10,u) # replace f(t,u) with f(t,-10) for u<-10
    return u*(1-u/12)-4*np.heaviside(-(t-5), 1)

plt.xlim([0, 10])
plt.ylim([0, 20])
t_plot = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
for N0 in ic:
    N1 = odeint(de, N0, t_plot, tfirst=True)
    plt.plot(t_plot, N1)
```

This results without any other changes in the plot

[image: plots of the integrated ODE]

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Could you explain why you placed `u=max(-10, u)` where you placed it? I know you mention that a linearly bounded RHS is numerically benign, but my question is this: when `odeint` calls `de`, it seems based on your solution that it's calling it with a specific value of `u`. What does this value represent?

Comment: It leaves `u` unchanged if larger than `-10`, so in the visible portion of the plot nothing is changed. Note that at `u==-10` the derivative is negative, thus there will be no "returning" solutions. The value is largely arbitrary, you could also take `-1` or `-50`, just safely away from the region for the plot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case [Lutz Lehmann's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361237/2640045) is nicer. But since I already coded it up I post my solution that stops the integral curve after it goes outside of the range too. Maybe that's useful to somebody coming to this thread one day.

```
ic = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

def de(t, u):
    return u*(1-u/12)-4*np.heaviside(-(t-5), 1)

for N0 in ic:
    # supressing ODEintWarning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        N1 = odeint(de, N0, np.linspace(0, 10, 10000), tfirst=True).reshape(-1)
    cond = (0 > N1) | (N1 > 20)
    stop_at = len(N1)-1 if np.all(~cond) else np.argmax(cond)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10000)[:stop_at], N1[:stop_at])
```

Comment: With solve_ivp one could implement that more directly using the "events" mechanism.